# Unique identifyer for a selection of IDs

Tags: database, math, discrete-mathematics

My problem relates to Excel and VBA but is applicable for all Database and programming.

I have around 500 posts with data. All are idenfied with a unique four digit number.

Example

- 1522
- 1643
- 1755
- 1888
- 1952
- 2022
- 2042
- etc.

Now, the user should be able so select an undetermined combination of these numbers and add a comment. Therefore I need to create a unique identfier for each combinaion of these numbers

For example the user should be able to choose 1522,1888,2022 and add a comment. And the user should be able to add another comment for the combination 2022,2042 etc.

I'm sure there is a best standard to create unique identifier for a combination of posts in a database?

Anyone that knows how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't *need to create a unique identfier for each combinaion of these numbers* at all.  You could get by just fine by creating comments with their own unique ids and implementing a many-to-many relationship between comments and posts.  And if posts and comments are the same thing, then you have a reflexive many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a unique value for each *possible* combination, then you'd need 2<sup>500</sup> different numbers at least. If you want to allow all four-digit numbers you'd be at 2<sup>10000</sup> instead. Way too big for realistic use.

Instead you need to concentrate on the *actually used* combinations. Store them in a table, i.e. a table with two columns, one for post ID and the other for comment ID. That way, you can have multiple posts for each comment, and you can have multiple comments for each post.

That's a classical many-to-many relationship here, which means database engineers have these (among others) in mind when tuning their database engines, so this will scale reasonably well. Of course, Excel is not a database engine, so that doesn't say much for your use case…

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering. I need a unique for a set of postID's (not to each and everyone). I solved it by MD5 hash the combination and thereby extract it for that unique combination only. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Olle: Hash values are not guaranteed to be unique; it's just for many application sufficiently unlikely that you get a hash collision in real life. Furthermore, I had assumed that you'd need some way to obtain information from the key. So that you can say “I have this comment, which posts does it refer to?” or “I have this post, which comments are referring to this (among others)?” Neither is feasible with a cryptographic hash function.

Comment: Yes, but since I (pretty static) have around 400 posts I hope that collisions won't occur. All I need is "I have this collection of posts - which comment is set for this collection", I only need to match a set of posts to a comment and not a comment to a set of posts. So that is OK.

Comment: So this is the thing. I need to have a set-up that connects _a set_ of posts. Not each post to _one_ comment. That's why i chose my, rather unorthodox, solution. And given that I do this in Excel, i found it to be a rather neat solution. :)